Do I have to create a new ssh key pair every time I try access my repositories from different servers?
I created an SSH key pair and added it to my GitHub repository 1-2 months ago. Now I want to connect from a new server. I want to clone the repository I have on my GitHub to this new server, but it says I don't have right access.
Do I have to create a new ssh key pair for it every time I try to clone (try to access) my repositories from a new server? Or is there any way I can use existing keys?
Some sources say add public key to the new machine, I did it creating id_rsa.pub and copying old servers public key here, but it did not work.

Why do you want to clone the repo to all these servers? Are you using that as a deployment mechanism?

@JimRedmond not really, i'm using sandboxes but they get destroyed after some time. That is why i wanted to know if i have to create a new one every time or not, because it becomes a chore

Are you only using the sandboxes to pull code and do things with it? Or are you using the sandboxes to write code? (Details are helpful.)

You can reuse the same key pair you created by copying it to each machine where from you want to access your GitHub repository. But this is a bad practice from a security point of view and I'd advise against it. GitHub allows associating multiple keys to your account so the better way would be creating a key pair for each machine.
If you decide to share the key pair across machines, make sure that keys have proper permissions (private key should have read/write for the owner, no permissions otherwise and public can also allow read for group and all). Also, make sure private key is added to the SSH agent.
